# Why did Black Widow say, "Please"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

> War Machine: It's definitely Barton. What he's done here...what he's
>   been doing for the last few years. I mean, the scene that he left. I
>   gotta tell you, there's a part of me that doesn't even wanna find him.
>
> Black Widow: Will you find out where he's going next?
>
> War Machine: Nat..
>
> Black Widow: **Please?**

Why did Black Widow say, "Please" in this scene?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### She says "please" asking Rhodey to find out where Barton is going next so that she can save him from what he's become

---

Following is the explanation (*the sentences in the brackets indicate what they meant*):

> **Natasha**: ***Will you find out where he's going next?***
>
> **Rhodey**: Nat.... (*in a concerned voice asking her to stop tracking
> Barton as he's gone, lost and doesn't need to be brought back*)
>
> **Natasha**: Please? (*requesting Rhodey to help her locate Barton*)